# How to limit insert data into mysql from a file using perl

Tags: mysql, perl, cgi

I am relatively new to Perl.I have been trying to insert data to database from a text file using a CGI script.I have written code for it and it's working properly.but when i try to impose a limit on the data that is inserted using LIMIT keyword there is a problem.Please check where i am going wrong and what needs to be amended.Thanks for your advice.

here is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use CGI ':standard';
use DBI;

if(param())
{
my @params=param();
my $limit=param('limit')||'';


my $dbh =DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:sample","root","");
my $var="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/test.txt' INTO TABLE sample2 FIELDS TERMINATED       BY '\n' WHERE LIMIT 0,$limit";
my $sth = $dbh->do($var) or die "prepare failed: " . $dbh->errstr();
print $sth ."Records inserted";

$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();

print
header(),
start_html(
-title=>'Welcome',
-text=>'#520063'
),
#h1("Records have been displayed"),
end_html();

}

else
{
print
header(),
start_html('A Simple Form'),
h1('Please enter the limit '),
start_form(),
'Limit: ',
textfield(-name=>'limit'),
br(),
#'Phone Number: ',
#textfield(-name => 'number'),
#br(),
submit(),
end_form(),
end_html();
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get from MySQL?  Did you try the command directly in MySQL?  I don't think `LOAD DATA` takes a `WHERE` nor a `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: `"there is a problem"` is a very common and very bad way to describe a problem. Just imagine someone going to the doctor: "When I got up this morning, there was a problem. Here's my body, can you tell me what's wrong with it?"

Comment: @TLP Doctor: "Sure! It's fat and ugly."

Comment: `$sth->finish()` should not work, and should cause a warning such as `Can't call method "finish" without a package or object reference`, since `do()` returns the number of affected rows, not a DBI object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without an error message I can't be totally sure, but the problem is likely in your SQL.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/test.txt'
INTO TABLE sample2
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n'
WHERE LIMIT 0,$limit
```

There's problems.

- There WHERE clause is empty (LIMIT is not part of the WHERE clause)
- LOAD DATA INFILE does not take a WHERE clause
- LOAD DATA INFILE does not take a LIMIT clause

Basically that whole last line won't work.  In general, if a SQL command doesn't work in a program try firing up the MySQL command line and debug the command there.

[LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) does not have a way to limit how many lines it will pull in, [this is an oft requested feature](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6373).  To work around it I would suggest copying and truncating the file before feeding it to MySQL.